# WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH for windows 8

Tags: selenium, path

I've tried all solutions of other threads. I am still having this issue.

> ```
> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
> ```

And in my system variable : 
'Path':

```
.....v1.0\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Go\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program\Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin;C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\browserdriver\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe;C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\browserdriver\geckodriver.exe
```

Python or Javascript. Not Java. On Windows

Is there something I am misunderstanding ?

Comment: I think you have to set path like `System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","Absolute path of Chrome driver");`

Comment: I am python or js, not Java.

Comment: Then Try `driver = webdriver.Chrome(C://Documents/SeleniumSupport/chromedriver.exe')` something like this

Comment: And for Firefox... Geckodriver is for firefox not Chrome

Comment: driver = webdriver.Firefox(C://Documents/SeleniumSupport/geckodriver.‌​exe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
path="C:/Users/me/AppData/Local/browserdriver/geckodriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=path)
```